# Need feedback and guidance on logo design for an animation studio

Tags: logo, typography, critique, design-principles, composition

I'm a junior graphic designer, in the middle of my last year as a student. I came here for some feedback and constructive criticism, because honesty I'm lost. To give you a little background, I took on a re-branding project for a local animation studio as a case for my diploma. Unfortunately, my views on the design and the concept I want to go with, do not match with what my teacher wants  so, there are some complications. Long story short, here are some concept sketches. You know how most animation studios have a sort of a mascot, like Disney had Mickey Mouse for a good while, Toei Animation has their variation of puss in boots, Ghibli has Totoro. So, inspired from that concept, i tried to think of a design where a character could be implemented. Plus, I think use of character could be more fun and more memorable for a brand that targets kids mostly.

The only issue and question that arises with the use of the character, is eligibility. How would it appear when scaled down. Considering that aspect, I tried to make the antennas of the character bolder. Still, I feel like, compared to last two, the first one, in terms of scale is better. But in the other two, the character might disappear when scaled down and become unreadable. The issue with first one, it the typography part. I wanted to go for something bubbly and round, but still as if written with a pencil, to relate to the whole concept of traditional animation. But it still somehow feels/looks unbalanced...

I'd appreciate some feedback on whether the concept ( which of the three) is good and how can I polish, develop then further. Thank you in advance

P.S. The name of the studio is a combination of two abbreviations, "AZ" ( which stands for Azerbaijan) and "An" ( which stands for animation)

[image: Variant 1]

[image: Variant 2]

[image: Variant 3]

Comment: Hello Night and welcome to GD.SE! Please review our [guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work). You can edit your question to make it more precise.

Comment: Welcome! I fear this question could use some self-editing. You are editorializing quite a bit. I'm not certain the entire first paragraph is even necessary. In order for answers to be *helpful* you need to try and ask direct, targeted, questions so they can be objectively voted on by other users. "Polls" such as "which one is best" are too opinion-based to be effectively answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logo is pretty good. I would give the character some eyes (otherwise it just looks like an abstract shape), and type the name horizontally and that would be it. Not bad at all.

You can have some fun with an AI image generator, give it this image below and ask it to generate variations. Separately, give it a specific request like *"make a cartoon style logo for an animation studio with a cute looking character"*. You will be surprised what they can come up with :))

The other two versions are not so good, in my opinion.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! It does seem too look much better and balanced with straightened sub text, and agree, the eyes could make it more alive

Answer (score 0):

As most of us probably could agree, the 3rd attempt has a good amount of integrity. One has already suggested you to straighten the name text and to insert some personality by adding eyes. That's OK. But have big enough human like eyes and big enough head for them.

I suggest generating an animated version as soon as possible. Let it be in the beginning straight and let the 4 big balls be equally sized. Let it live and move a little to get smoothly the final form in say 2 seconds and also turn the face towards the watcher. Let the eyes open and in the same time let the business name suddenly appear below the body. Add also some sound to emphasize the eye opening. Then it freezes to the final form.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! I've actually tried to stylize the bug mascot a little more to add personality to it and use big eyes. Though I'm not sure how well would it work when scaled down ![Stylized variant](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1089836089822421012/1090677827621363722/Screenshot_2023-03-27-18-17-09-862_org.readera-01.jpg)